# Weighted variance-covariance matrices and lapply

Tags: r, covariance, lapply

I have a list `prob` with 50 elements. Each element is a 601x3 matrix of probabilities, each row of which represents a complete sample space (i.e., each row of each matrix sums to 1). For instance, here are the first five rows of the first element of `prob`:

```
> prob[[1]][1:5,]

           [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
 [1,] 0.6027004 0.3655563 0.03174335
 [2,] 0.6013667 0.3665756 0.03205767
 [3,] 0.6000306 0.3675946 0.03237481
 [4,] 0.5986921 0.3686131 0.03269480
 [5,] 0.5973513 0.3696311 0.03301765
```

Now, what I want to do is to create the following matrix *for each row of each matrix/element* in the list `prob`. Taking the first row, let a = .603, b = .366, and c = .032 (rounding to three decimal places). Then,

```
> w
         [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
 [1,] a*(1-a)       -a*b       -a*c
 [2,]    -b*a    b*(1-b)       -b*c
 [3,]    -c*a       -c*b    c*(1-c)
```

Such that:

```
> w
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
 [1,]  0.239391  -0.220698  -0.019296
 [2,] -0.220698   0.232044  -0.011712
 [3,] -0.019296  -0.011712   0.030976
```

I want to obtain a similar 3x3 matrix 600 more times (for the rest of the rows of this matrix) and then to repeat this entire process 49 more times for the rest of the elements of `prob`. The only thing I can think of is to call `apply` within `lapply` so that I am accessing each row of each matrix one-at-a-time. I'm sure that is not an elegant way to do this (not to mention I can't get it to work), but I can't think of anything else. Can anyone help me out with this? I'd also love to hear suggestions for using a different structure (e.g., is it bad to use matrices within lists?).

Comment: Is 601*50 matrices the result you are looking for? Do you have idea how you would like to store them (as a list, in one matrix)? Or maybe you do not need to store them.

Comment: I'm not really sure what type of output I'm looking for -- I can't quite decide what would be best in this case. They array solution, below, looks promising. I definitely want to store the output, though. I will need to use these 3x3 matrices immediately after they're created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running this process with `lapply` on a list of similarly dimensioned matrices should be very simple. If it represents a challenge, then you should post the `dput(.)` output for a two element list with similar matrices. The challenge is really to do the processing row by row which is illustrated here with the output being a 3x3xN array:

```
w <- apply(M, 1, function(rw) diag( rw*(1-rw) ) + 
                    rbind( rw*c(0, -rw[1], -rw[1] ), 
                           rw*c(-rw[2],0, -rw[2] ),
                           rw*c(-rw[3], -rw[3], 0)
         )

 )
 w
             [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]
 [1,]  0.23945263  0.23972479  0.23999388  0.24025987  0.24052272
 [2,] -0.22032093 -0.22044636 -0.22056801 -0.22068575 -0.22079962
 [3,] -0.01913173 -0.01927842 -0.01942588 -0.01957412 -0.01972314
 [4,] -0.22032093 -0.22044636 -0.22056801 -0.22068575 -0.22079962
 [5,]  0.23192489  0.23219793  0.23246881  0.23273748  0.23300395
 [6,] -0.01160398 -0.01175156 -0.01190081 -0.01205173 -0.01220435
 [7,] -0.01913173 -0.01927842 -0.01942588 -0.01957412 -0.01972314
 [8,] -0.01160398 -0.01175156 -0.01190081 -0.01205173 -0.01220435
 [9,]  0.03073571  0.03102998  0.03132668  0.03162585  0.03192748

 w <- array(w, c(3,3,5) )
 w
, , 1

            [,1]        [,2]        [,3]
[1,]  0.23945263 -0.22032093 -0.01913173
[2,] -0.22032093  0.23192489 -0.01160398
[3,] -0.01913173 -0.01160398  0.03073571

, , 2

            [,1]        [,2]        [,3]
[1,]  0.23972479 -0.22044636 -0.01927842
[2,] -0.22044636  0.23219793 -0.01175156
[3,] -0.01927842 -0.01175156  0.03102998

.... snipped remaining output
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion to use arrays @DWin -- I think I will end up going this route. I'm a little confused by your example but that's most likely just my limited knowledge of R. I think that this was enough to point me in the right direction, though, so thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry it was confusing. Basically I just add a diagonal matrix to a matrix with the off-diagonal elements of your specification for each row. That gives me a 9-row matrix with each column being the constructed from one row of your input. Because matrices and arrays are column-major in R, you can turn each of those columns into a 3 x 3 "slice" of an array that has as many slices as your input has rows. You get one slice at a time with w[ , , 1] ; w[ ,, 2], etc.